# Find the probability?

Tags: probability

The examination results of the first year mathematics papers are normally distributed with an average mark of 65 and a standard deviation of 10. If it was decided that the top 2.5 percent of the students should be given distinction grades, what should be the cut-off mark for a distinction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, $1.96$ gets engraved on the brain. For a normal, being more than $1.96$  standard deviation units above the mean has probability $0.025$.

If that is not yet familiar,  look for $0.975$ in the **body** of a usual standard normal table.

So the cut-off point is $65+(1.96)(10)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $X \equiv$ exam result. Then $X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(65, 10^2)$. We are asked to find a cut-off mark $k$ such that:
$$
Pr(X > k)=0.025
$$
Standardizing to $Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$ yields:
$$
Pr\left(Z>\dfrac{k-65}{10}\right) = 0.025
$$
Can you take it from here?